# How do I use question marks in quotes in quotes?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks, end-punctuation

For example, would I write:

"What do you mean by, 'It's not over yet?'"

Or

"What do you mean by, 'It's not over yet'?"

The thing the speaker is quoting is not a question, so where would the question mark go? I use American punctuation.

Comment: There seems to be a series of questions asking the same thing, but [the last (or first) question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3499) is closed itself for needing details, so I think this can remain open. It might still be an informative read, though.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Maybe I missed something, but I don't see a *single* instance in that linked question of ***Quotes within quotes***. They're all just about how to punctuate a "reported speech" question, wherein the issue of alternating between single and double quote marks simply doesn't arise. And there was me thinking I might include example **1c** in my answer here, to start with **Did she just say '[entirety of example 1b text, including all punctuation marks]?'.** Purely to illustrate Peter Shor's point about alternating, even when "nesting" down ***four*** levels!

Comment: @FF OP here is asking solely about the use of question marks in sentences such as 'Did she ask "Where is my brother?" ' /  'Did she ask "Where is my brother"?' / 'Did she ask "Where is my brother?"?'  Andrew's answer has << Both the "inner" question and the "outer" question end in the same place, and both need a question mark. In this case, there's a convention that punctuation is not duplicated and it's the inner question which prevails. ...
[but] It's entirely possible that the pronunciation is context-dependent, in which case the punctuation is, too. >> ...

Comment: Positioning of the question mark otherwise comes within the inverted commas offsetting the quoted question. // [Are two question marks correct in a sentence ... Did she say, "Where's the coffee?"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295832/are-two-question-marks-correct-in-a-sentence/295833#295833) is also relevant.

Answer (score 2):

From [How to Punctuate Quotations - a practical handout](https://www.csuchico.edu/slc/_assets/documents/writing-center-handouts/quotation-marks-handout.pdf)

> Rule #5
> *Question marks should go inside of the quotation marks if the quote is a question. If the quote is not a question,
> but the sentence is, the question mark should be outside the quotation marks.*

> Examples:
> 1: *The caterpillar answered, “Who are you?”*
> 2: *Why did you say that I was “ugly and annoying”?*

So I guess we could extend those examples...

> 1a: *"**I think** his exact words were 'The caterpillar answered, "Who are you?"'"* <sup>**1**</sup>
> 1b: *"**Do you think** his exact words were 'The caterpillar answered, "Who are you?"'?"*

Things might get even messier using *British* punctuation (where the question mark goes *after* "the" closing quote - but good luck finding ***the*** relevant quote mark! :)

---

<sup>**1**</sup> From [a comment by Peter Shor](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3499/how-are-embedded-quotations-used#comment136287_3553) under the original (closed) question on this issue:
*If you have inner inner quotes, you go back to double quotes. If you have more than three layers of quotes, you keep alternating.*